# How to use javascript to implement cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am making a javascript game and in order to save progress I am implementing cookies. I have looked at many tutorials but I cant seem to find one that just saves a variable and then gets the variable from the cookie at a later time only if there is a cookie on the users system. Does anyone know how to implement this? Thanks!
Requirements:
Creates a cookie containing multiple variables
Access the cookie at a later time
Thats it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Usage:

Create session cookie:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
```

Create expiring cookie, valid across entire site:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

Read cookie:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie'); // => "the_value"
$.cookie('the_cookie', { raw: true }); // => "the_value" not URL decoded
$.cookie('not_existing'); // => null
```

Delete cookie:

```
// returns false => No cookie found
// returns true  => A cookie was found
$.removeCookie('the_cookie'[, options]);
```

Note: when deleting a cookie, you must pass the exact same path, domain and secure options that were used to set the cookie, unless you're relying on the default options that is.

Comment: Did he say jquery? Is this tagged as jquery?

Comment: @tntu so what ? did he say he doesn't want to use jQuery ?

Comment: Hmm how do I implement jquery into my code?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: Click the link I gave you and no more head eke with jQuery. Besides jQuery does not always play nice with simple JavaScript. All major games use custom built JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this.

http://robert.accettura.com/blog/2012/01/17/localstorage-with-cookie-fallback/

If you are going to build a game you should use localstorage where available it's better the cookies. It has an automated cookie fallback if localstorage not available.